# nltk was unable to find mace4

Tags: python, nltk

While executing below code, I am getting error as mentioned.

I downloaded the required package from http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/download/ and configure. But still same issue.

I am getting this error:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> dt = nltk.DiscourseTester(['A student dances', 'Every student is a person'])
>>> dt.readings()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/discourse.py", line 351, in readings
    self._construct_threads()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/discourse.py", line 297, in _construct_threads
    consistency_checked = self._check_consistency(self._threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/discourse.py", line 393, in _check_consistency
    modelfound = mb.build_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/api.py", line 333, in build_model
    verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 202, in _build_model
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 215, in _call_mace4
    self._mace4_bin = self._find_binary('mace4', verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/inference/prover9.py", line 166, in _find_binary
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 544, in find_binary
    binary_names, url, verbose))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 538, in find_binary_iter
    url, verbose):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 517, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the mace4 file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the PROVER9HOME environment variable.

  Searched in:
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/prover9
    - /usr/local/share/prover9
```

While configuring the LADR-2009-11 through `make all`, ended process with

```
.o utilities.o provers.o foffer.o ../ladr/libladr.a
search.o: In function `search':
search.c:(.text+0x6e54): undefined reference to `round'
../ladr/libladr.a(avltree.o): In function `avl_item_at_position':
avltree.c:(.text+0x7cb): undefined reference to `ceil'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [prover9] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Desktop/karim/software/LADR-2009-11A/provers.src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me. I found it on github [issue 193](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_book/issues/193)

In brief

- download [gui](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/gui/v05.html)
- download [dll](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/mace4/gui/MSVCP71.DLL)
- place downloaded dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Prover9-Mace4`
- create Windows system environment variable PROVER9 and set it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Prover9-Mace4\bin-win32`

Answer (score 0):

```
NLTK was unable to find the mace4
```

and

```
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Maybe it's obvious, but you need to have a successful build of LADR/Prover9. Only after that, you can use `nltk.Prover9()` or `nltk.MaceCommand(...)`

so why is there an compilation error? see some possible answers here [use gcc flags: `-std=c99` and `-lm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400616/undefined-references-to-c-math-library-on-ubuntu) in your make file

Answer (score 0):

The user @mircea already answered a similar question about Prover9 and Mace. Check it out [Unable to Open Prover9 and Mace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006405/unable-to-open-up-prover9-mace4) . It is about setting the path to your library like

`prover = nltk.Prover9()`
`prover.config_prover9(r'd:/prover9/bin')`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by modifying the nltk/inference/prover9.py file. In line 144, where `binary_locations(self)` is defined I added the path to this folder:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Prover9-Mace4\bin-win32` (Notice: not the prover folder, but the bin-win32 subfolder). There you will find both the `prover9.exe` and the `mace4.exe` files.

Lastly, I don't know if this is relevant but I downloaded the GUI found here: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/gui/v05.html. Using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem today. Fixed it by moving `-lm` to the end of the line in all the lines involving `-lm`. Edit file `Makefile` in `LADR-2009-11A/provers.src` to make it look like the following:

```
 65 prover9: prover9.o $(OBJECTS)
 66     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o prover9 prover9.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 67
 68 fof-prover9: fof-prover9.o $(OBJECTS)
 69     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o fof-prover9 fof-prover9.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 70
 71 ladr_to_tptp: ladr_to_tptp.o $(OBJECTS)
 72     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ladr_to_tptp ladr_to_tptp.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 73
 74 tptp_to_ladr: tptp_to_ladr.o $(OBJECTS)
 75     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o tptp_to_ladr tptp_to_ladr.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 76
 77 autosketches4: autosketches4.o $(OBJECTS)
 78     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o autosketches4 autosketches4.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 79
 80 newauto: newauto.o $(OBJECTS)
 81     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o newauto newauto.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
 82
 83 newsax: newsax.o $(OBJECTS)
 84     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o newsax newsax.o $(OBJECTS) ../ladr/libladr.a -lm
```