# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DrtParser'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I already checked all similar thread, but no help.

```
>>> from nltk import load_parser
>>> parser = load_parser('grammars/book_grammars/drt.fcfg', logic_parser=nltk.sem.drt.DrtParser())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DrtParser'
```

code is given at : http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html just above 5.2

```
>>> print nltk.sem.drt
<module 'nltk.sem.drt' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/sem/drt.pyc'>
```

what can be the issue?

`/nltk/sem` has drt.py and drt.pyc files

Comment: seems that [`DrtParser` code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blame/ad04ad8425328eeaee6c6fa6dad2a9af54d2c416/nltk/sem/drt.py#L50) was added very recently. you may want to check you are using most recent version.

Comment: @behzad.nouri: I guess I have most updated one, just recently I have python 2.7.3. do I need to check anything else?

Comment: check `nltk.__version__`

Comment: @behzad.nouri: it's '3.0.0b1',  any issue with this?

Comment: Hmm, 1. `sudo pip install -U nltk`  now version is `3.0` and error gone

Comment: @behzad.nouri: any help to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844794/nltk-was-unable-to-find-mace4