# Unable to open up prover9/Mace4

Tags: python, nltk

## I using a code and in it I try to use Prover9 but for some reason this keeps popping up. I downloaded both applications but I have no idea where to put them in order to open it.

NLTK was unable to find the mace4 file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the PROVER9 environment variable.

Searched in:
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/prover9
    - /usr/local/share/prover9

===========================================================================

Answer (score 3):

use method **config_prover9** for a nltk.Prover9 object to provide the path to the installed Prover9 software

```
read_expr = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring
SnF = read_expr('SnF')
NotFnS = read_expr('-FnS')
R = read_expr('SnF -> -FnS')

prover = nltk.Prover9()
prover.config_prover9(r'd:/prover9/bin')
prover.prove(NotFnS, [SnF, R])
```

my **prover9.exe** is located on **d:\prover9\bin** (windows 7 system). use something similar for *ux systems.