# Setting path for macecommand for nltk

Tags: nltk, nltk-book

I found a solution to set the path for prover9 from the link 
[config_prover9 method for setting prover9 path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006405/unable-to-open-up-prover9-mace4)
Is there any similar method for dealing with macecommand too? My code is below

```
a4 = read_expr('exists y. (woman(y) & all x. (man(x) ->love(x,y)))')
a5 = read_expr('man(adam)')
a6 = read_expr('woman(eve)')
g = read_expr('love(adam,eve)')
mc = nltk.MaceCommand(g, assumptions=[a4, a5, a6])
mc.build_model()
```

Is there any way to set it to find the directory where I have installed Macecommand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just needed to set environment variable for it.